# Send value from an input generated by the onSubmit callback

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

When i add files to the queue i generate a text input for each file.

Is it possible to send this input's value to the server side?

I tried adding the value to the params object like this:

```
up._options.request.params.description = id;
```

but it only sends the id of the last image.

```
var up = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
    button: document.getElementById("addFiles"),
    request: {
        params: {
            action: "upload",
        },
        endpoint: config.uploadURL,
    },
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "mkv", "mp4"],
    },
    autoUpload: false,
    callbacks: {
        onSubmit: function(id, fileName, response) {
            var element = document.createElement("li");
            element.setAttribute("id", "qImage-"+id);
            element.setAttribute("class", "qImage");
            $(".imagesList").prepend(element);

            var out  = "<div class='fileInfo'>";
                out += "<span id='qCancel-"+id+"'>Cancel </span>";
                out += fileName;
                out += "</div>";
                out += "<div class='fileData'>";
                out += "<label for='fileDescription'>Description</label>";
                out += "<input type='text' name='fileDescription' id='fileDescription'>";
                out += "</div>";

            $("#qImage-"+id).html(out);

            $("#qCancel-"+id).on("click", function(){
                up.cancel(id);
                $("#qImage-"+id).remove();
            });
            up._options.request.params.description = id;
        },
    }
});
$('#startUpload').on("click", function(){
    up.uploadStoredFiles();
    //document.getElementById('queue-list').innerHTML = '';
});

$('#cancelUpload').on("click", function(){
    up.cancelAll();
});
```

Comment: http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setParams

Comment: @RayNicholus thank you, should have looked more carefully through the docs.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Ray's comment, there are two methods to my knowledge. The first may be exclusive to the S3 implementation, but I use:

```
uploadSuccess: {
  endpoint: "link",
  params: {
     key: value
  }
}
```

Or utilize setParams if you want it sent along with the file upload request itself.